# Lumia 1020 keeps hanging

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-1020, lumia

I've just been sent a replacement 1020 as mine developed a screen fault. I'm starting to wish I hadn't bothered...

The new one has been hanging about twice a day, maybe more. Sometimes when the screen is off, other times when it shows the lock/clock screen - it just stops updating the screen and cannot be unlocked. I have to soft-reset (power+volume down).

It is a a brand new phone with no SIM yet installed, upgraded to 8.1 Denim as soon as it detected Wifi.
I allowed it to restore itself from my Live ID 'backup' and added a screen protector - that's it.

Does this seem a slam-dunk faulty unit, or could it be something I can address? The phone is not under warranty (I sent it away for a replacement screen but they sent me a new phone without charging more).

**update:** I also did a factory reset and *didn't* restore a previous backup, this has not helped. And I now recall that it actually hung right out of the box when I plugged it in to charge before doing *anything*...

Answer (score 1):

Hanging of phone this frequently depicts something is wrong with the device.

Check for any update you phone have (either OS or softwares)

If your phone and all apps are up to date, try finding out by doing which task on your phone, it hangs. Is there any specific app which causes this scenario (then uninstall the app and check again) or it hangs without doing anything as well.

Second suggestion is, try charging your phone to 100% before plugging it out.

Or you can connect it to your system and scan for viruses (chances are very less that it might got attacked by any virus)

Lumia phones have this drawback (only my observation, not written anywhere though)